# What's wrong here I have to do NPM link on "react": "^16.13.1" because app report duplicate React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, peer-dependencies

It started with this error:

[image]

So I did a test to rule out what the problem was. I tested if the library [Notistack](https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack) that I hade forked from GitHub, and then linked with [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-link/) to my app, was the problem.

I placed this code in the app

```
window.React2 = require('react');
console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);
```

And I placed this code in forked Notistack

```
window.React1 = require('react');
```

When I run the app I can see in the console that I get a `false` from that test. Indication that I have two different React version and that causing the error.

If I now do npm link in the library for the React package, so that the Notistack is using the app's version of React. Then I get rid of this error.

What am I missing here why do I have to do this even I use `peerDependencies` for React.

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5"
},
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "notistack",
    "version": "1.0.10",
    "description": "Highly customizable notification snackbars (toasts) that can be stacked on top of each other",
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "module": "dist/notistack.esm.js",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
    "license": "MIT",
    "author": {
        "name": "Hossein Dehnokhalaji",
        "email": "hossein.dehnavi98@yahoo.com",
        "url": "https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack"
    },
    "homepage": "https://www.iamhosseindhv.com/notistack",
    "repository": {
        "url": "git+https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack.git",
        "type": "git"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsdx build --transpileOnly --entry ./src/index.js",
        "prebuild": "npm run docs",
        "prepublishOnly": "npm run build",
        "docs": "rimraf typedoc.json && typedoc --tsconfig",
        "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.0.0",
        "react": "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.5",
        "@types/node": "^13.9.0",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.23",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
        "@types/react-is": "^16.7.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.9.1",
        "babel-plugin-optimize-clsx": "^2.6.1",
        "eslint": "^7.7.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "~18.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "~2.22.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.6",
        "react": "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0",
        "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
        "rollup-plugin-bundle-size": "^1.0.3",
        "rollup-plugin-copy": "^3.3.0",
        "tsdx": "^0.13.2",
        "typedoc": "^0.16.11",
        "typescript": "^3.8.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "clsx": "^1.1.0",
        "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.3.0"
    },
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack/issues"
    },
    "funding": {
        "type": "opencollective",
        "url": "https://opencollective.com/notistack"
    },
    "contributors": [
        "Hossein Dehnokhalaji (https://www.iamhosseindhv.com/)"
    ],
    "keywords": [
        "notistack",
        "enqueueSnackbar",
        "snackbarprovider",
        "useSnackbar",
        "multiple",
        "react",
        "javascript",
        "material-ui",
        "toast",
        "redux",
        "snackbar",
        "stacked",
        "notification",
        "material design",
        "hossein",
        "dehnokhalaji",
        "iamhosseindhv"
    ]
}
```